# How to filter and create a new database in r based on the latest observation and date rows?

Tags: r

any help is much appreciated!

I have an extended database (more than 1000), and I would like to eliminate some rows and keep only the latest information on each individual's name. I have no idea how to start.

Original Database

| Name | Year | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2021-04-03 | 203 |
| John | 2022-08-02 | 198 |
| John | 2018-08-34 | 234 |
| Patrick | 2014-05-09 | 176 |
| Patrick | 2021-03-09 | 199 |
| Patrick | 2020-09-03 | 200 |
| Peter | 2019-09-05 | 204 |
| Peter | 2017-07-14 | 209 |
| Peter | 2019-10-05 | 199 |

Final Database

| Name | Year | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2022-08-02 | 198 |
| Patrick | 2021-03-09 | 199 |
| Peter | 2019-10-05 | 199 |

Answer (score 1):

We could use `slice_max`

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
df1 %>%
    slice_max(Year, by = 'Name')
```

-output

```
     Name       Year Weight
1    John 2022-08-02    198
2 Patrick 2021-03-09    199
3   Peter 2019-10-05    199
```

---

Or with previous versions of `dplyr`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(Name) %>%
   slice_max(Year) %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Name    Year       Weight
  <chr>   <chr>       <int>
1 John    2022-08-02    198
2 Patrick 2021-03-09    199
3 Peter   2019-10-05    199
```

---

Or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[which.max(as.Date(Year))], Name]$V1]
      Name       Year Weight
1:    John 2022-08-02    198
2: Patrick 2021-03-09    199
3:   Peter 2019-10-05    199
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("John", "John", "John", "Patrick", "Patrick", 
"Patrick", "Peter", "Peter", "Peter"), Year = c("2021-04-03", 
"2022-08-02", "2018-08-34", "2014-05-09", "2021-03-09", "2020-09-03", 
"2019-09-05", "2017-07-14", "2019-10-05"), Weight = c(203L, 198L, 
234L, 176L, 199L, 200L, 204L, 209L, 199L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: getting the error: Error in `slice_max()`:
! `...` must be empty.
✖ Problematic argument:
• .by = "Name"
Backtrace:
 1. df1%>% slice_max(Year, .by = "FName")
 3. dplyr:::slice_max.data.frame(., Year, .by = "Name")

Comment: @GabrielBarbosa you may have an older dplyr version.  Try the updated solutions

Comment: @GabrielBarbosa Also, I think you used `.by` instead of `by` ( i had a typo earlier)